# Concatenating a string to a file of strings on each line

Tags: bash, shell, unix

Say I have a file named `usernames.txt` and in front of all of the usernames I want to add `@`. I want to either add `@` and overwrite to that file, or just save it in another file. See below for my current state and what I want to achieve:

Current state:

```
jake
eve
mallory
bob
sam
```

Future state:

```
@jake
@eve
@mallory
@bob
@sam
```

**EDIT**: Figured it out, anyone in the future with a similar problem - see my solution below!

```
while read -r line;
do
  printf '@%s\n' "$line"
done < file1.txt > newFile.txt
```

Comment: Wondering why this question get upvoted. No effort shown...